# ¿Cómo puedo crear una Query en sql server, utilizando como tabla base una función de fechas y enlazándolo con otra tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

estoy intentando crear una query utilizando una función de fechas y una tabla de turnos, que pueda mostrarme los turnos de trabajadores cada día, cuando tenga turno o descanso según sea el dia,

**con que cuento:**
1- cuento con una función de fechas que me arroja un rango de fechas que yo agregue, adjunto ejemplo:

[image: resultado función de fechas]

2-cuento con una tabla de turnos, con solo los dias que una persona tiene turno, si un dia tiene descanso no sale la fecha ni la fila, adjunto ejemplo:

[image: resultado tabla de turnos]

se puede ver que en la tabla de turnos solo hay registros cuando una persona tiene turno.

**Problema:**
cuando realizo el join entre la función y la tabla de turnos a través del campo fecha, el resultado es que solo me muestra registro cuando tiene turno y no no me coloca la fecha cuando tiene descanso, adjunto ejemplo:

[image: Resultado del join]

**Resultado Deseado:**

[image: resultado deseado]

la idea es que cuando el trabajador tenga descanso quede la fila en blanco solo mostrando la fecha y su ID, o que diga la palabra descanso.

**espero que me puedan ayudar.
muchas gracias.**

Comment: Prueba con `LEFT JOIN` en lugar de `JOIN`.

Comment: acabo de realizar la prueba con LEFT JOIN y me arroja el mismo resultado que con el JOIN.

Comment: Necesitas compartir el código como texto, no como imagen. También muestra el código completo, ya que usando un `LEFT JOIN` debería de traer todas las fechas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para estos casos es muy útil el patrón *cross join -> left join*. Para lo cual necesitas tres conjuntos:

1. El universo de fechas (tu función de rango de fechas).
2. El universo de turnos (tu función donde obtienes los turnos asignados).
3. El universo de trabajadores. No nos lo presentaste, pero imagino que existe una tabla de trabajadores con su id y otros datos.

Este patrón consiste en hacer un `cross join` entre el universo de trabajadores y el de fechas, seguido de un `left join` con el universo de turnos. De esta forma puedes obtener los datos de los trabajadores que tengan o no turnos asignados. (sí, aunque siempre te digan que no hagas producto cartesiano, lo correcto es hacerlo cuando sea útil y no sin querer :).

Te dejo un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que hice en mysql porque es lo que tengo a mano:

```
create table trabajador (id int, nombre varchar(15), otros_campos varchar(15) null);
insert into trabajador(id, nombre) 
values
    (1, 'pedro'),
    (2, 'juan'),
    (3, 'andres');

create table fechas(fecha date);
insert into fechas(fecha) 
values
  ('2021-10-01'),
  ('2021-10-02'),
  ('2021-10-03'),
  ('2021-10-04');

create table turnos(id int, fecha datetime, otros_campos varchar(15) null, trabajador_id int);
insert into turnos(id, fecha, trabajador_id)
values
  (1, '2021-10-01', 1),
  (2, '2021-10-03', 1),
  (3, '2021-10-04', 2);

select 
  f.fecha, 
  t.id, 
  turnos.otros_campos, 
  case
    when trabajador_id is null then 'DESCANSO' 
    else 'Calculo de Jornada' 
  end as jornada 
from 
    /*  Con el cross join se generan todas las combinaciones de
       trabajadores y fechas, así puedes obtener el id del 
       trabajador que no sale si solo utilizas LEFT JOIN */
  trabajador as t cross join fechas as f 
   /*  Esta es la parte importante, el left join evita que 
      explote el número de resultados siempre y cuando 
      uses la doble condicion */
  left join turnos 
    on turnos.fecha = f.fecha and turnos.trabajador_id = t.id
/*where t.id = 1*/ //Puedes filtrar por trabajador y lo que mejor te parezca
order by t.id, f.fecha; // y obviamente puedes ordenar para que sea más simple de interpretar
```

Este es el resultado que daría esto que te ejemplifiqué.

| fecha | id | otros_campos | jornada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | (null) | Calculo de Jornada |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-03 | 1 | (null) | Calculo de Jornada |
| 2021-10-04 | 1 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-02 | 2 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-03 | 2 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | (null) | Calculo de Jornada |
| 2021-10-01 | 3 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-02 | 3 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-03 | 3 | (null) | DESCANSO |
| 2021-10-04 | 3 | (null) | DESCANSO |

Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

PD: Me olvidaba de invitarte a visitar [Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que siempre viene bien :)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y sugerencia, me ayudaste a resolver mi inquietud.